# Visual Studio 2013 Slow IDE Responsiveness

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For some unknow reason, Visual Studio 2013's IDE seems less responsive. It should be fairly snapping considering that I'm running it on a high end PC with lots of RAM. This happens even when I am not debugging my web application.

When I click on menus, there's a noticable delay before it responds and there's no highlighting of the menu. Clicking on HTML text or items in the solution explorer is also slow. Sometimes there's a pause with the cursor stuck on a text selection state.

Here's my configuration from the Help screen:

> Version 12.0.30324.00 Update 2 RC Microsoft .NET Framework Version
>   4.5.50938
>
> Installed Version: Ultimate
>
> Architecture and Modeling Tools   Microsoft Architecture and Modeling
>   Tools
>        UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States
>   and other countries.
>
> LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual
>   Studio 2013
>
> Microsoft Office Developer Tools - Update 1 for Visual Studio 2013 ENU
>   Microsoft Office Developer Tools - Update 1 for Visual Studio 2013 ENU
>
> Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   Microsoft Team Explorer for
>   Visual Studio 2013
>
> Visual Basic 2013   Microsoft Visual Basic 2013
>
> Visual C# 2013   Microsoft Visual C# 2013
>
> Visual C++ 2013   Microsoft Visual C++ 2013
>
> Visual F# 2013   Microsoft Visual F# 2013
>
> Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   Microsoft® Visual
>   Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker
>
> Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system ©
>   1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third
>   Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version
>   licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   2013.2.50314
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.1.20303.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.1 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Windows Azure Tools.
>
> Entity Framework Power Tools   1.0 Adds useful design-time DbContext
>   features to the Visual Studio Solution Explorer context menu.
>
> JetBrains ReSharper 8.2   Full Edition build 8.2.0.2160 on
>   2014-03-20T23:53:08 JetBrains ReSharper 8.2 package for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit
>   http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2014 JetBrains,
>   Inc.
>
> MySQL for Visual Studio   1.1.3 Data design and management tools for
>   MySQL.  Copyright © 2007-2013 Oracle, Inc.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50313.46 NuGet Package Manager in Visual
>   Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit
>   http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.40403.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> Web Essentials 2013   1.0 Adds many useful features to Visual Studio
>   for web developers.
>
> Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.1 Windows Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> Windows Azure Remote Debugging   1.0 Windows Azure Remote Debugging
>   Community Technology Preview
>
> Windows Azure Tools   2.2 Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2013 - v2.2.11003.1601
>
> Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration   1.0 This package integrates the
>   tools for the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK into the menus and controls of
>   Visual Studio.
>
> Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0 This package contains the necessary
>   Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
>
> Xsd2Code For more information about , see the  website at
>   http://www.codeplex.com/Xsd2Code Copyright (c) Pascal Cabanel 2009 
>   Inc.

Can anything here be the culprit? FYI, I removed the Visual Experience stuff and didn't help.

UPDATE:
There's an error message that appears in ActivityLog.xml:

> 1203 ERROR System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is
>   not implemented. at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SecondaryVsTextBufferAdapter.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.GetCurFile(String&
>   ppszFilename, UInt32& pnFormatIndex) at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.IVsExtensions.GetFileName(IPropertyOwner
>   owner) at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Css.UnusedCssTagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection
>   spans) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.<GetTagsForBuffer>d__5.MoveNext()
>   Editor or Editor Extension 2014/04/15 12:35:42.788  1204 ERROR
>   System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not
>   implemented. at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SecondaryVsTextBufferAdapter.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.GetCurFile(String&
>   ppszFilename, UInt32& pnFormatIndex) at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.IVsExtensions.GetFileName(IPropertyOwner
>   owner) at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Css.UnusedCssTagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection
>   spans) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.d__5.MoveNext()
>   Editor or Editor Extension 2014/04/15 12:35:42.940

Comment: Did it slow down after you install 2013 Update 2 RC?

Comment: I have the same issue with slowness on clicking menus, etc on Visual Studio 2013 Premium. And it's especially slow when I open the Team Members node. I'm not sure if it's Visual Studio or if it's Lync that is causing the slowness. Visual Studio 2012 however runs quite faster on the same PC than 2013.

Comment: I can't really tell, but I think it may have something to do with the update. Also, why has this been voted for a close? What counts as a question these days of SO?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  This started once I installed Update 2 RC.

Comment: To those who closed this as off-topic: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. You may be able to get help on Super User." (emphasis mine) I vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks @Joce.  The folks on SO should do something about this problem.  It's already getting into the absurd territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MadsKristen.EditorExtensions namespace is a part of the Web Essentials 2013 extension.

More information: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/863

You can fix this error by waiting for the next update or updating to the night build: http://vswebessentials.com/download#nightly